# jQuery on-scroll event for mobile

Tags: html, jquery, css, iphone, mobile

I have a fairly simple code, that will change the background colour of the navigation bar from transparent to white when the user starts scrolling down the page. I have used jQuery to implement the action, adding a class to the div when the user starts scrolling.

However, the scrolling action does not work on mobile/tablets (iPhone/iPad) in this instance.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

jQuery:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
      $(window).on("scroll", function() {
          if($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
              $("#menuholder").addClass("active");
                $("#menuwaves").addClass("active");
          } else {
              
             $("#menuholder").removeClass("active");
             $("#menuwaves").removeClass("active");
          }
      });
  });
</script>
```

CSS

```
#menuholder.active {
  background-color: #f0ecea;
}
#menuholder{
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1200px;
  height: 85px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="menuholder">

<img src="healthwavelogo.png" class="menu_logo"></img>


<div class="mobile_menu">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>


<div class="menu_options">
<div><a href="#">#HEALTHTECH</a></div>
<div><a href="">SOLUTIONS</a></div>
<div><a href="">PROJECTS</a></div>
<div><a href="">ABOUT</a></div>
<div><a href="">CONTACT</a></div>
</div>

</div>
<div id="menuwaves"></div>
```

Comment: Can you also provide the HTML?

Comment: Sure, edited :)

Comment: The code seems okay :| And seems to be working well.

Comment: The scroll is only working went scrolling past the footer of the page on a mobile device.... very strange :|

Comment: I have managed to sort it by changing the page wrapped div to absolute from relative.....

Comment: better post the answer so other that may encounter the same problem will find your answer. @jiml123